# typedef struct error: expected a ';'

Tags: c, gcc

```
#pragma once
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
} msg_gps_time_t;
```

I have this code and it gives the following error: expected a ';'
The code is expected to work since i got it from a 3rd party as part of a tutorial.

Comment: You missed to give your `struct` a name.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Or alternatively, that's just an unnamed struct.

Comment: @zenith Or the planned struct name is the 'space bar' token

Comment: [Compiles fine for me](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tNQI5SLSnspsxo8b).

Comment: Is this a C or a C++ question?

Comment: @FUZxxl Neither really: there's no `__attribute__` in the C or C++ standards.

Comment: @FUZxxl empty structs declarations in C are undefined behavior, so I guess we should retag it to C++ (but so is the attributes keyword.. but then again that keyword isn't part of either C or C++, so the question of which applies becomes moot IMO).

Comment: @ᐅJohannesSchaub-litbᐊ gcc accepts them as GNU extension to C and the code has attributes which are also a GNU extension

Comment: @ouah so I guess we shall remove both of C and C++ and add gnuc

Answer (score -1):

It should be:

```
typedef struct  {
} __attribute__((packed)) msg_gps_time_t;
```

The attribute has to come after the structure declaration.

Comment: ["You may specify type attributes in an enum, struct or union type declaration or definition by placing them immediately after the `struct`, `union` or `enum` keyword. __A less preferred syntax is to place them just past the closing curly brace__ of the definition."](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html)

Comment: @zenith it probably depends on the gcc version or is a gcc bug, I have the same error as OP with my gcc version; putting the attributes after removes the error.